# Excel Powerquery Import, keep custom column stick to table

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

Let's say I have a export excel file that looks like this:

| Order No. | Name | Quanity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bart | 2 |
| 2 | Lisa | 1 |
| 3 | Homer | 5 |

I import this table using powerquery and maybe merge it with some other tables.
No I want to have a "comment" column like this, that is managed in the Excel file.

| Order No. | Name | Quanity | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bart | 2 | Bad behavior |
| 2 | Lisa | 1 |  |
| 3 | Homer | 5 | Bad liquidity |

When power query updates my exported list and an item is removed or added, the following will happen:

| Order No. | Name | Quanity | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Lisa | 1 | Bad behavior |
| 3 | Homer | 5 | Bad liquidity |

The comment line will not stick to the according item as it doesn't "remeber" what it's linked to.

What is the easiest, most pracitical way to achieve "sticky comments"? I tried searching the web but didn't manage to find anything useful (maybe because I don't know how to describe it correctly).

Comment: Don't have time to show it, but search for `self referencing tables` in Power Query for how to accomplish this task.